# Inventory Profit calculation in spark-scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

A table of 5-tuples `(PRODUCT_ID, TRANSACTION_TYPE, QUANTITY, PRICE, DATE)`. `Transaction_Type` could be one of "Buy" or "Sell". 
`Quantity` is the number of instances of the product is bought or sold, for the `Price` indicated on the `Date`.

A product that is sold is offset against the inventory already in hand, and that too the earliest instance of that inventory.

Net Profit is calculated by offsetting the Sold inventory against the earliest Bought inventory, and if that doesn't fully address it, then use the next Bought inventory, and so on.

For instance, consider the following table values:

```
1, Buy, 10, 100.0, Jan 1

2, Buy, 20, 200.0, Jan 2

1, Buy, 15, 150.0, Jan 3

1, Sell, 5, 120.0, Jan 5

1, Sell, 10, 125.0, Jan 6
```

There are hundreds of files stored already on HDFS having the schema shown above.

Then the profit calculation should work as follows:

- When Product 1 is sold on Jan 5, those 5 units should offset against
  the Jan 1 Buy transaction first (resulting in a profit of
  5*(120.0-100.0)).
- Then when Product 1 is further sold on Jan 6, since
  the units sold are more than what remains from Jan1 Buy lot, Jan 3's Buy lot can be considered for the remainder.
- That is, the profit from selling Product 1 on Jan 6 is 5*(125.0-100.0)+5*(125.00-150.0).
- So, the profit value for Jan 6 transaction is = 5 * (25) + 5 * (-25 ) = 125 - 125 = 0. and
  the net profit until Jan 6 is 100 (from Jan 5 transaction) + 0 (from Jan 6 transaction) = 100.
- Calculate the final profit as of the last date present in that data.

Below is the code snippet. But It does not work getting NullPointer Exception. Any better suggestion ?

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.rdd._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row


case class Inventory(PRODUCT_ID: Int, TRANSACTION_TYPE: String, QUANTITY: Long, PRICE: Double, DATE: String)

object MatchingInventory{
    def main(args:Array[String])= {

        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("XYZ")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)


        val sqlcontext = new SQLContext(sc)
        // Create a schema RDD of Inventory objects from the data that has any number of text file.
        import sqlcontext.implicits._
        val dfInvent= sc.textFile("Invent.txt")
        .map(_.split(","))
        .map(p => Inventory(p(0).trim.toInt, p(1).trim, p(2).trim.toLong, p(3).trim.toDouble, p(4).trim))
        .toDF().cache()
        dfInvent.show()

        val idDF =  dfInvent.map{row => row.getInt(0)}.distinct 
        //idDF.show()
        val netProfit = sc.accumulator(0.0)
        idDF.foreach{id =>
        val sellDF = dfInvent.filter((dfInvent("PRODUCT_ID").contains(id)) && (dfInvent("TRANSACTION_TYPE").contains("Sell")))
        val buyDF = dfInvent.filter((dfInvent("PRODUCT_ID").contains(id)) && (dfInvent("TRANSACTION_TYPE").contains("Buy")))    
         var soldQ:Long = sellDF.map{row => row.getLong(2)}.reduce(_+_) 
         var sellPrice:Double = sellDF.map{row => row.getLong(2)*row.getDouble(3)}.reduce(_+_) //reduce sends the result back to driver
         var profit:Double = 0.0
         // profit for each bought item
         buyDF.foreach{row => 
                           if((soldQ > 0) && (soldQ < row.getLong(2))){profit += sellPrice -(soldQ*row.getDouble(3));soldQ = 0}
                           else if((soldQ > 0) && (soldQ > row.getLong(2))){profit += sellPrice - (row.getLong(2)*row.getDouble(3));soldQ = soldQ - row.getLong(2)}
                                else{}} 
        netProfit += profit}
        println("Inventory net Profit" + netProfit)
    }

}
```

Comment: "Any good approach to solve this problem?" It's clearly an assignment so to get most value from it, I suggest an approach of trying to solve it yourself, and when you get a specific issue, you post a question describing that issue and maybe people will help.

Comment: Few questions : You are creating a new dataframe in map function. When you call the map function on a dataframe I guess, this function is called by every row in every worker? Will it not create problems ? I mean a dataframe inside a map function means every worker will create a dataframe right? I may be wrong here as I am also a newbie to spark

Comment: Null pointer exception error-6/09/20 12:21:59 WARN TaskMemoryManager: leak a page: org.apache.spark.unsafe.memory.MemoryBlock@6438aac7 in task 404
6/09/20 12:21:59 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 174.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 405)java.lang.NullPointerException
       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.resolve(Dataset.scala:218)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.col(Dataset.scala:921)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.apply(Dataset.scala:908)
 MatchingInventory$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Inventory.scala:33) at MatchingInventory$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Inventory.scala:32)

Comment: "It crashes" is never enough of an explanation of a problem.  You don't provide a [mcve] and so it's difficult to say what the problem is. I don't have time to get it to compile, and I don't have your data file anyway. Please add the current code you are using, details of the error and so on

Comment: @The Archetypal Paul - I have edited the code section. But It crashes. Is it because nested action and transformation here? But dataframes are different inside "idDF.foreach" loop.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The above code section has the updated code.The data file I m using for testing has the below data in txt file  1,Buy,10,100.0,Jan 1
2,Buy,20,200.0,Jan 2
1,Buy,15,150.0,Jan 3
1,Sell,5,120.0,Jan 5
1,Sell,10,125.0,Jan 6

Comment: it's missing imports, among other things so it will not compile and is not complete. You still haven't provided details of "it crashes" means (or,  if it's that backtrace) how far it got when it did crash. I don't have time right now in any case as I'm at work, but if you provide the details perhaps someone else will spot the problem

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this. This is a workable code, only issue is I am using collect at the later stage to sync between buy and sell which will lead to memory issues for large data.

```
from pyspark.sql import  SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext
import sys
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

if __name__ == "__main__":

    sc = SparkContext()

    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
    df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='false', inferschema='true').load('test.csv')

    df = df.withColumn("C1", ltrim(df.C1))

    df.registerTempTable("tempTable")
    df = sqlContext.sql("select * from tempTable order by C0")

    dt = df.map(lambda s: (str(s[0])+'-'+ s[1], str(s[2]) + ',' +str(s[3])))
    dt = dt.reduceByKey(lambda a, b : a + '-' + b)

    ds = dt.collect()

    dicTran = {}
    for x in ds:
        key = (x[0].split('-'))[0]
        tratype = (x[0].split('-'))[1]


        val = {}
        if key in dicTran:
            val = dicTran[key]

        val[tratype] = x[1]
        dicTran[key] = val

    profit = 0

    for key, value in dicTran.iteritems():
        if 'Sell' in value:
            buy = value['Buy']
            sell = value['Sell']

            ls = sell.split('-')
            sellAmount = 0
            sellquant = 0
            for x in ls:
                y = x.split(',')
                sellAmount= sellAmount + float(y[0]) * float(y[1])
                sellquant = sellquant + float(y[0])

            lb = buy.split('-')
            for x in lb:
                y = x.split(',')

                if float(y[0]) >= sellquant:
                    profit += sellAmount - sellquant * float(y[1])
                else:
                    sellAmount -= float(y[0]) * float(y[1])
                    sellquant -= float(y[0])

    print 'profit', profit    



    #
```

Here is the logic I thought

1) For all same ids and transaction type I concat the quantity and price via a separator
2) Then I collect and split them to calculate the profit

I know this will crash on large data sets as collect is used but could not thing of anything better. I will try out your solution as well.

Comment: Sorry to say but I am not familiar with python.

Comment: @Advika : I mentioned the logic as well.

Answer (score 0):

So here I come up with a solution

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.rdd._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.sql.Date
import scala.math.Ordering


//Defining Schema
case class Inventory(PRODUCT_ID: Int, TRANSACTION_TYPE: String, QUANTITY: Long, PRICE: Double, pDate:java.sql.Date)


object MatchingInventory{
    def main(args:Array[String])= {

        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("XYZ")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)


        val sqlcontext = new SQLContext(sc)

        import sqlcontext.implicits._

        val format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d")
        //Read data from directory which has multple files
        val dfInvent= sc.textFile("data/*.txt")
        .map(_.split(","))
        .map(p => Inventory(p(0).trim.toInt, p(1).trim, p(2).trim.toLong, p(3).trim.toDouble, new Date(format.parse(p(4)).getTime)))
        .cache()

        def calculateProfit(data:Iterable[Inventory]):Double  = {
            var soldQ:Long = 0
            var sellPrice:Double = 0
            var profit:Double = 0
            val v = data

            for(i <- v ){
                if(i.TRANSACTION_TYPE == "Sell")
                {
                  soldQ = soldQ + i.QUANTITY
                  profit = profit+ i.PRICE*i.QUANTITY

                }
            }

            for(i <- v){
                if(i.TRANSACTION_TYPE == "Buy")
                {
                    if((soldQ > 0) && (soldQ < i.QUANTITY || soldQ == i.QUANTITY)){profit = profit -(soldQ*i.PRICE);soldQ = 0}
                    else if((soldQ > 0) && (soldQ > i.QUANTITY)){profit = profit - (i.QUANTITY*i.PRICE);soldQ = soldQ - i.QUANTITY}
                    else{}
                }
            }
           profit
        }

        val key: RDD[((Int), Iterable[Inventory])] = dfInvent.keyBy(r => (r.PRODUCT_ID)).groupByKey
        val values: RDD[((Int), List[Inventory])] = key.mapValues(v => v.toList.sortBy(_.pDate.getTime))


        val pro = values.map{ case(k,v) => (k, calculateProfit(v))}
        val netProfit = pro.map{ case(k,v) => v}.reduce(_+_)
        println("Inventory NetProfit" + netProfit)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer so it might be useful for others.

**You could follow this algorithm:**

- Calculate the cumulative sum for the sells and buys for the current row and all prev rows, and consider the sell qty with negative
- Calculate the cumulative sum for the sales only for the current row and all following rows, so you can get the total sold items at the oldest buy qty
- Get the difference between the first two and consider it as the actual consumed-qty
- Group by product and calculate the profit/loss

**Input:**

```scala
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val data = Seq(
        (1, "Buy", 10, 100.0, "Jan 1"),
        (2, "Buy", 20, 200.0, "Jan 2"),
        (1, "Buy", 15, 150.0, "Jan 3"),
        (1, "Sell", 5, 120.0, "Jan 5"),
        (1, "Sell", 10, 125.0, "Jan 6"))

val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF("PRODUCT_ID", "TYPE", "QTY", "PRICE", "DATE")
```

**Calculate consumed qty:**

```scala
// Calculate cumulative sum for sells and buys for the current and all prev rows 
val cumSumWind = Window.partitionBy("PRODUCT_ID").orderBy("DATE").rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
val df2 = df.withColumn("cum_sum", sum(when(col("TYPE") === "Sell",  col("QTY") * -1).otherwise(col("QTY"))).over(cumSumWind))

// Calculate cumulative sum for sells only for the current and all following rows
val sellCumSumWind = Window.partitionBy("PRODUCT_ID").orderBy("DATE").rangeBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)
val df3 = df2.withColumn("sell_cum_sum", sum(when(col("TYPE") === "Sell", col("QTY")).otherwise(0)).over(sellCumSumWind))

// Calculate the actual consumed qty
val df4 = df3.withColumn("cons_qty", when(col("TYPE") === "Sell", col("QTY")) 
                                .when(col("sell_cum_sum") > col("cum_sum"), col("QTY"))
                                // If negative then nothing is consumed from this row
                                .when((col("QTY") - (col("cum_sum") - col("sell_cum_sum"))) < 0, 0)
                                .otherwise(col("QTY") - (col("cum_sum") - col("sell_cum_sum"))))
df4.show()
```

```
+----------+----+---+-----+-----+-------+------------+--------+
|PRODUCT_ID|TYPE|QTY|PRICE| DATE|cum_sum|sell_cum_sum|cons_qty|
+----------+----+---+-----+-----+-------+------------+--------+
|         1| Buy| 10|100.0|Jan 1|     10|          15|      10|
|         1| Buy| 15|150.0|Jan 3|     25|          15|       5|
|         1|Sell|  5|120.0|Jan 5|     20|          15|       5|
|         1|Sell| 10|125.0|Jan 6|     10|          10|      10|
|         2| Buy| 20|200.0|Jan 2|     20|           0|       0|
+----------+----+---+-----+-----+-------+------------+--------+
```

**Calculate global profit/loss per product:**

```scala
// Groupby product and calculate the profit/loss
val result = df4.groupBy("PRODUCT_ID").agg(
        sum(when(col("TYPE") === "Buy", col("PRICE") * col("cons_qty") * -1)
                .otherwise(col("PRICE") * col("cons_qty"))
        ).alias("profit_loss"))
result.show()
```

```
+----------+-----------+
|PRODUCT_ID|profit_loss|
+----------+-----------+
|         1|      100.0|
|         2|        0.0|
+----------+-----------+
```

You can find the python version at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76564056/1477418