# I need to calculate profit/loss for given stock data set, ensuring that the first bought items are sold first

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hive

Consider the following sample dataset.

| Date | symbol | qty | price per qty | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07 July 2022 | REL2300PE | 200 | 50 | buy |
| 07 July 2022 | IDBI2300PE | 200 | 50 | sell |
| 15 July 2022 | REL2300PE | 100 | 50 | buy |
| 15 July 2022 | IDBI2300PE | 20 | 50 | buy |
| 16 July 2022 | REL2300PE | 200 | 35 | buy |
| 30 July 2022 | IDBI2300PE | 60 | 50 | sell |
| 30 July 2022 | REL2300PE | 450 | 45 | sell |
| 30 July 2022 | IDBI2300PE | 200 | 25 | sell |

If we focus on the stock symbol 'REL2300PE', it is being sold in quantities of 450, resulting in a total sale value of $20,250. Now, let's calculate the cost price for the first 450 units of this stock. The cost price can be calculated by summing up the product of the quantity and price per quantity for each buying trade associated with this stock. In this case, the cost price for the first 450 units is calculated as follows: 200 units * $50 + 100 units * $50 + 150 units * $35 = $20,250. Since the sale value and the cost price for the first 450 units are the same ($20,250), the profit/loss for this stock should be 0.

Comment: You have described a standard FIFO inventory accounting.   What is your question?  If it is 'how to calculate cost basis with SQL', then join the sell transactions with all buys and sells for that security occurring before the sale date, calculate a share balance subtracting all prior sells from each buy using window functions, and keep the buys that are between 0 and the number of shares in the sale.  The shares will be either the whole buy amount or sell minus buy amount, so Least(buyamt,sellamt - buyamt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You could follow this algorithm:**

- Calculate the cumulative sum for the sells and buys for the current row and all prev rows, and consider the sell qty with negative
- Calculate the cumulative sum for the sales only for the current row and all following rows, so you can get the total sold items at the oldest buy qty
- Get the difference between the first two and consider it as the actual consumed-qty
- Group by symbol/product and calculate the profit/loss

**Input:**

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, sum

data = [\
    ('05 July 2022', 'IDBI2300PE', 500, 45, 'buy'),\
    ('07 July 2022', 'REL2300PE', 200, 50, 'buy'),\
    ('07 July 2022', 'IDBI2300PE', 200, 50, 'sell'),\
    ('15 July 2022', 'REL2300PE', 100, 50, 'buy'),\
    ('15 July 2022', 'IDBI2300PE', 20, 50, 'buy'),\
    ('16 July 2022', 'REL2300PE', 200, 35, 'buy'),\
    ('20 July 2022', 'REL2300PE', 200, 45, 'sell'),\
    ('30 July 2022', 'IDBI2300PE', 60, 50, 'sell'),\
    ('30 July 2022', 'REL2300PE', 250, 45, 'sell'),\
    ('31 July 2022', 'IDBI2300PE', 200, 25, 'sell')]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Date", "symbol", "qty", "price", "type"])
```

**Calculate consumed qty:**

```py
# Calculate cumulative sum for sells and buys for the current and all prev rows 
cum_sum_wind = Window.partitionBy('symbol').orderBy('Date').rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
df = df.withColumn('cum_sum', sum(when(col('type') == 'sell', -1 * col('qty'))\
                                    .otherwise(col('qty'))).over(cum_sum_wind))

# Calculate cumulative sum for sells only for the current and all following rows
sell_cum_sum_wind = Window.partitionBy('symbol').orderBy('Date').rangeBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)
df = df.withColumn('sell_cum_sum', sum(when(col('type') == 'sell', col('qty'))\
                                         .otherwise(0)).over(sell_cum_sum_wind))

# Calculate the actual consumed qty
df = df.withColumn('cons_qty', when(col('type') == 'sell', col('qty'))\ 
                                .when(col('sell_cum_sum') > col('cum_sum'), col('qty'))\
                                # If negative then nothing is consumed from this row
                                .when((col('qty') - (col('cum_sum') - col('sell_cum_sum'))) < 0, 0)\
                                .otherwise(col('qty') - (col('cum_sum') - col('sell_cum_sum'))))

df.show()
```

```
+------------+----------+---+-----+----+-------+------------+--------+
|        Date|    symbol|qty|price|type|cum_sum|sell_cum_sum|cons_qty|
+------------+----------+---+-----+----+-------+------------+--------+
|05 July 2022|IDBI2300PE|500|   45| buy|    500|         460|     460|
|07 July 2022|IDBI2300PE|200|   50|sell|    300|         460|     200|
|15 July 2022|IDBI2300PE| 20|   50| buy|    320|         260|       0|
|30 July 2022|IDBI2300PE| 60|   50|sell|    260|         260|      60|
|31 July 2022|IDBI2300PE|200|   25|sell|     60|         200|     200|
|07 July 2022| REL2300PE|200|   50| buy|    200|         450|     200|
|15 July 2022| REL2300PE|100|   50| buy|    300|         450|     100|
|16 July 2022| REL2300PE|200|   35| buy|    500|         450|     150|
|20 July 2022| REL2300PE|200|   45|sell|    300|         450|     200|
|30 July 2022| REL2300PE|250|   45|sell|     50|         250|     250|
+------------+----------+---+-----+----+-------+------------+--------+
```

**Calculate global profit/loss per symbol:**

```py
# Groupby symbol and calculate the profit/loss
result = df.groupby('symbol')\
    .agg(
        sum(when(col('type') == 'buy', -1 * col('price') * col('cons_qty'))\
                .otherwise(col('price') * col('cons_qty'))\
        ).alias("profit_loss"))
result.show()
```

```
+----------+-----------+
|    symbol|profit_loss|
+----------+-----------+
|IDBI2300PE|      -2700|
| REL2300PE|          0|
+----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column total_price using `withColumn` using additional calculation as multiply by -1 to total_price if type is 'buy' and multiply by 1 if type is 'sell'

```
df = df.withColumn('total_price', when(df.type == 'buy', (df.qty * df.price_per_qty * (-1))).otherwise(df.qty*df.price_per_qty) 
df = df.groupBy(col('symbol')).sum(col('total_price').alias('profit_loss'))
```

Please try to understand my concept here. There may be code syntax error as I don't have laptop now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Hive to solve this problem you can use below query to get the desired result:

```
    select date
    ,symbol
    ,sum(qty * (CASE 
                    WHEN type='buy' THEN price_per_qty 
                    ELSE (price_per_qty*(-1)) 
                    END
                )
        )  over (partition by symbol order by date  rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as total_profit
        ,row_number() over( partition by symbol order by date desc ) as rn
    from stock1) as running_sum where rn=1;
```